# Java music not working

Tags: java, audio

I made a java program and wanted a background music so I used this function

```
public static void playSound(final String url) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem
                            .getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + url));
                    clip.open(inputStream);
                    clip.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

only problem is when I try to run the 27 minute wav file, it speeds it up really fast

Comment: hmmm don't know the answer but `synchronized` on a function that just starts a Thread isn't needed I think

Comment: @niceman k thanks for the advice :)